# SPDisposeCheck telling me not to dispose of a Sharepoint Web

Tags: sharepoint-2010, dispose, using

```
using (var web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb)
{
    //Some code
}
```

The SPDisposeCheck tool is telling me not to dispose of this object - but I thought this was a prime example of where you *should* dispose of an SP object!?

Output from SPDisposeCheck:

**Notes: Dispose should not be called on this object.
Initial Assignment: web := Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.get_Current().{Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext}get_Site().{Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite}get_RootWeb()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SPContext object live for the whole life cycle of the request. If you dispose it's inner Web or Site property, you will break other SharePoint components that may request this properties later in the life of the request.

To be simple, only dispose Web and Site you created. Not ones managed by SharePoint engine.

PS: did you considered to post on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't really understand when a programmer might create a new web that needs disposing of though? Aren't they (i.e. the sharepoint's inner objects) all passed by reference anyway? +1.

Comment: you have to create SPWeb objects in several scenarios, including : running RunWithElevatedPrivileges, working outside the web application (console application, timer job), working with another SPWeb than the current one, etc.

Comment: But even if you refer to another web other than the current one - it's still one that already exists - so disposing of that could affect any other dependencies in the object model in the same way couldn't it? (If that's the reason you're giving for not disposing of RootWeb). Thanks again.

Comment: if you call `new SPSite("your site collection url")` or 'anySite.OpenWeb("your sub web url")`, you can consider you have to dispose it.

Answer (score -1):

Is that really correct?
If you you look at the code for SPSite.RootWeb, it looks like this:

```
public SPWeb RootWeb
{
    get
    {
       if (this.m_rootWeb == null)
       {
          this.m_rootWeb = this.OpenWeb(this.ServerRelativeUrl);
          this.m_rootWebCreated = true;
       }
       return this.m_rootWeb;
    }
}
```

It actually does a OpenWeb and then you SHOULD dispose it. Or am I wrong?